# Bloqueando rotas para determinado tipo de Usuario no Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-rotas, laravel-5.3

Este é meu primeiro post aqui. Estou começando a usar o Laravel 5.3 para criar um sistema.
Neste sistema eu terei dois tipos de usuários(Admin e Cliente). Eu gostaria de bloquear certas rotas para o cliente. 
Eu consegui limitar os clientes de visualizar certos itens das views(usando roles), mas gostaria de bloquear as rotas para ter mais segurança. Como eu poderia dizer para o sistema só aceite usuarios admin acessem a rota delete, por exemplo ?

Desculpem se é uma pergunta meio idiota, mas estou aprendendo e estou meio sem rumo.

Comment: Essa pergunta é duplicada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para controlar o acesso de usuários às rotas você deve usar `middlewares`.

A documentação do Laravel explica bem como usar : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware

Exemplo:

Você pode definir em um middleware que só pessoas com idade maior que 20 anos acesse determinada rota. O middleware pode ser definido:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class CheckAge
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->age <= 20) {
            return redirect('home');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Para incluir na rota:

```
Route::get('adultos', function () {
    //
})->middleware('auth');
```

Este é um exemplo bem simples, recomendo que leia toda a documentação para entender realmente como usar e todas as opções de uso.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. consegui realizar as limitações